# Using WHERE with function in Sequelize query

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use a function, `JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH()`, in my Sequelize query:

```
MyModel.query({
  where: sequelize.where(
    sequelize.fn('JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH', sequelize.col('cues')),
    0
  )
});
```

This doesn't seem to work.  It generates a bad query:

```
SELECT id, title, /* etc. etc. */
FROM MyModel
WHERE
  `MyModel`.`attribute` = JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(`cues)` AND
  `MyModel`.`comparator` = '=' AND
  `MyModel`.`logic` = 0;
```

What is all this `attribute`, `comparator`, and `logic` stuff, and how do I turn it off?

The [documentation](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/querying/) seems to support what I'm doing.  Its example:

```
Post.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('char_length', sequelize.col('status')), 6)
});
// SELECT * FROM post WHERE char_length(status) = 6;
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've stumbled on a bug:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6440

This has been fixed in more recent builds:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/9730/commits/3b2972db2c494c8a4118a7e6c16aad0fc2e0eebe

The workaround around for now was to wrap my query with AND:

```
MyModel.query({
  where: {
    [sequelize.Op.and]: sequelize.where(
      sequelize.fn('JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH', sequelize.col('cues')),
      0
    )
  }
});
```